# Функция в Javascript, которая принимает радиус «r» (в сантиметрах) часов и угол «градус» часовой стрелки

Tags: javascript

Функция в **JavaScript**, которая принимает радиус `r` (в сантиметрах) часов и угол `градус(alpha)` часовой стрелки. На основе этих параметров ваша функция вычислит положение минутной стрелки и вернет область `S` меньшего сектора между двумя стрелками.

```js
function a(r, alpha) {
  var m = 0,
    h = 0,
    s = 0;
  h = alpha / 30;
  m = 60 * (h - Math.floor(h));
  m = Math.abs(30 * Math.floor(h) - m * 6);
  angle = Math.min(m, 360 - m);
  s = (Math.PI * Math.pow(r, 2) * angle) / 360;
  return s;
}
document.write(a(10, 130))
```

Что не так?

Comment: Sorry, this part of SO is for questions in Russian. Please, use stackoverflow.com for questions in English or translate your question.

Comment: "What is wrong?" - almost everything.

Comment: @Igor можете мне помочь?

Comment: так вы сначала вопрос свой на русский переведите в соответствии с правилами сообщества.

Comment: Могу. Надо все-таки перевести вопрос на русский язык.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Предполагается, что обе стрелки движутся плавно, без рывков.*

```js
function a(r, alphaH) {
  var alphaM = (alphaH - Math.floor(alphaH / 30) * 30) / 30 * 360;
  var delta = alphaH > alphaM? (alphaH - alphaM) : (alphaM - alphaH);
  if (delta > 180)
    delta = 360 - delta;
  console.log("Angles: h =", alphaH, ", m =", alphaM, ", delta =", delta);
  return Math.PI * r * r * delta / 360;
}
console.log("Sector area:", a(10, 135).toFixed(3));
console.log("Sector area:", a(10, 130).toFixed(3));
console.log("Sector area:", a(10, 180).toFixed(3));
console.log("Sector area:", a(10, 270).toFixed(3));
```

Comment: работает это неправильно потому что если градус будет 135,это значит что стрелка будет на 16:30,соответственно минутная стрелка должен быть ровно на 30,а не на 15.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');

submitButton.addEventListener('click', handleSubmit);

function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const radiusInput = document.getElementById('radius');
  const radius = radiusInput.value;
  const angleHourInput = document.getElementById('angle');
  const angleHour = angleHourInput.value;
  
const hour = Math.floor(angleHour / 30);
const minute = (angleHour - hour * 30) * 2;
const angleMinute = minute * 6;
const delta = Math.abs(angleMinute - angleHour);
const S = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2) * delta / 360;
  console.log('radius', radius);
  console.log('angleMinute', angleMinute);
  console.log('delta', delta);
  console.log('S', S);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form class="form container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="radius">Radius</label>
    <input id="radius" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="angle">Angle</label>
    <input id="angle" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate</button>
</form>
```